# Rename Couchbase Document (Without Sending/Receiving Contents)?

Tags: c#, couchbase

Is there a command to rename Couchbase documents without having to transfer the document contents?

Preferably with the C# client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In order to rename a document you must get the current document, change the key, store that document in Couchbase, and then delete the old document.